# Column 1 and 2 are equal or the same then column 3 defaults to yes

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, validation, sharepoint-list

[image]I want to change a column to yes if two other columns are equal, so same title and report week.

So if report week column and title are the same, then duplicate entry is yes.

```
=IF[Report week][Title]<>,[Duplicate Entry]="Yes"
```

Comment: Do you want `Duplicate Entry` column to be edited from list forms and force users to select "Yes" or "No"? Or you want this column to be calculated column based on other two column values?

Comment: Calculated based on the other 2 columns being equal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to [create a calculated column](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-create-a-calculated-column-in-a-sharepoint-list-or-library/), use this formula:

```
=IF([Report week] = [Title], "Yes", "No")
```

[image]

**Microsoft documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14))
2. [IF function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/0a4ad187-dba3-48ae-abe9-bbe3aa6aebca)

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

---

**Update from Comments**:

Comparing two list items/rows using calculated column **formula** is not possible in SharePoint. You can only compare columns for single list item/row.

Comment: with that formula both report week and title have to be the same? I want it to stay "no if the reprt week is the same but title is different. there is no formula for the duplicate value column

Comment: So Title Column and Report week have to both be equal to change Duplicate entry to "yes"

Comment: Are you trying to compare multiple list items (rows) using calculated columns? Or two columns (Report week & Title) for the same list item/row?

Comment: So 2 columns have to be equal to change 3rd column to yes. So lets say Name and week are equal, data will still populate but duplicate column will default to yes. Can you share a screen shot?

Comment: Comparing two list items/rows using calculated column **formula** is not possible in SharePoint. You can only compare columns for single list item/row.